# Minimum energy transfer orbit for n-body system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Is it possible, in principle, to calculate a minimum energy transfer orbit between any two bodies in an n-body system?  Even if one specifies a maximum elapsed time?  My intuition is that, except in special cases, there can be no analytical answer.

Comment: n-body systems don't have stable, long-term predictable orbits, so it's not even clear what your question is supposed to mean, I am afraid. In practice, of course, one can treat weakly coupled n-body systems with a central mass like the Kepler problem, and that's pretty much what we are doing. As for applications for spacecraft... whether one needs 617 lbs. of fuel or 616.7 lbs. is of not much concern to the spacecraft navigator. If you look at spacecraft, they carry fairly heavy balancing weights to move the center of mass to where propulsion system stability requires it to be.